# Snowflake role creation with minimum privileges

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to create a role in snowflake without any privileges or minimum privileges ?

I tried to create a role with parent role security-admin .

when I assign this role to user i am able to see databases of parent role also.

After I created role with parent role as public still I am able to see databases

what shall I do that a created role should not have access to any unless I grant it ?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a role, it does not come with any privileges. The role can only access the objects granted to role PUBLIC:

```
use role accountadmin;
create role testing_role;
grant role testing_role to user gokhan;
use role testing_role;

show databases;

SAMPLE_DATA ...

show grants to role testing_role;
```

The last command will return zero rows. Are you sure you switch to the role when checking databases? Also note that UI has separate roles for worksheets and the tabs:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-worksheet.html#overview-of-features

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html